# Vert.x eventBuses down

Tags: vert.x

I have the next issue.

We use in our microservices vert.x and use event buses. All seem good, but after some time, or big broadcasting for our system or maybe something another(unfortunately we didn't find anything), our evenbuses not works correctly: we have a situation like Schrodinger cat, we don't know what happens after next request, healthCheck returns different results after all new request for our services.

Regards.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how you set up the event bus? Are you using Hazelcast? After what time/amount of messages that occurs?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Hi, I use Ignite and I have the problem after 200-400 messages per second. after that event buses not reply response

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with cluster manager, not EventBus itself. You can confirm that by raising two nodes, one remove and one local, that are subscribed to the same message. Vert.x will use regular TCP for local notes on same machine, and your cluster manager for remote nodes.